# mock a promise method of a class

Tags: angular

I have this class:

```
@Injectable()
class ServiceOne {

method1(): Promise<any>{

return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
   // do stuff
   let value  = 1;

   resolve({'value':1});

});

}


}
```

my second service makes use of ServiceOne

```
@Injectable()
class ServiceTwo {

 gradeValue(): Promise<any>{
   const that : any = this;
   return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
     this.serviceOne.method1().then(value=>{
      let grade = 'F'
      console.log(`processing value ${value}`); // not reading this value at all
     // apply grading logic to value
      resolve(grade)
    });
    });

 }
}
```

Now i want to test my gradeValue method for different values, thus mock serviceOne.method1 but so far, i am not entering that specific block:

```
   it("should grade 1 as A", done=>(
      inject(
        [
          ServiceTwo,
          ServiceOne
        ],
        (
          service: ServiceTwo,
          oneService: ServiceOne
        ) => {

          spyOn(oneService, "method1").and.callFake(() => {
            console.log('can see this console')
            return Promise.resolve(1);
          });
          service
            .gradeLevel()
            .then(grade => {
              expect(grade).toEqual('A');
            })
            .catch(err => {});

          done();

        }
      )
    ));
```

The mocked method don't resolve to any value. How do i mock method1 so it returns value 1 when called/in use?

Answer (score 0):

In order to mock a promise method in a class that is used by another class, you need to inject the class you want to mock by using dependency injection. Angular has this batteries included. See their [guide](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection).

To do this properly you need to:

1. The ServiceTwo class does not inject ServiceOne anywhere. Not sure if this was omitted for brevity, but you need to inject ServiceOne into ServiceTwo in order to mock ServiceOne. You can inject ServiceOne in using the ServiceTwo constructor like so.

```
@Injectable()
class ServiceTwo {

    constructor(serviceOne: ServiceOne){}

     gradeValue(): Promise<any>{
         const that : any = this;
         return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
         this.serviceOne.method1().then(value=>{
             let grade = 'F'
             console.log(`processing value ${value}`); // not reading this value at all
             // apply grading logic to value
             resolve(grade)
        });
    });
}
```

You can test your service with dependencies a couple different ways.

1. Manually inject the service's dependencies by hand.

```
it('should grade 1 as A', function(done) {
    const serviceOne = new ServiceOne();
    spyOn(serviceOne, 'method1').and.callFake(() => Promise.resolve(1));
    const service = new ServiceTwo(serviceOne);

    service.gradeValue() // <-- make sure you are calling the correct service method.
        .then(grade => {
            expect(grade).toBe('A');
            done(); <-- done needs to be called inside the callback.
    });

})
```

2. Using Angular TestBed to handle DI for you.

```
beforeEach(function() {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({ providers: [ServiceOne, ServiceTwo] });
});

it('should grade 1 as A', function(done) {
    const service = TestBed.get(ServiceTwo);

    service.gradeValue()
        .then(grade => {
            expect(grade).toBe('A');
            done();
    });
})
```

There are plenty more examples in [Angular's service testing guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests).